# Error while building XLS from MySQL data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I have some code that written in php to use for export data from mysql to xls, but I have something wrong with the output php.

here's the code

```
<?php
// koneksi database
$db = "k8665xxxx";

mysql_connect("localhost","k866xxx","kixxx");
mysql_select_db("$db");

$date = date('d-m-Y');
$filename = "Data-inquiry-downloaded-$date.xls";

// nilai awal counter untuk jumlah data yang sukses dan yang gagal diimport
$sukses = 0;
$gagal = 0;
$table = "promo";


//jumlah kolom
$jkolom=0;

//generate kolom
$q= mysql_query("select * from $table where last_update between '$_POST[DariTanggal]' AND '$_POST[SampaiTanggal]'");
$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
foreach ($r as $head=>$nilai) {
$judul = str_replace("Promo","Inquiry","$head");
$header .=$judul."\t"; //print header table
$jkolom++;
}
$header .= "\n";

//generate baris
$result= mysql_query("select * from $table where last_update between '$_POST[DariTanggal]' AND '$_POST[SampaiTanggal]'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
for ($x=0; $x<$jkolom; $x++) {
$content .=$row[$x]."\t";
}
$content .= $row[$x]."\n";
}


$output .= $header.$content;
header('Content-type:application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $output;

?>
```

And here's the output...

```
622 Joni    bekasi  2193850955      4/11/2012                   spooring        yani    TELP        Bekasi  deal
623 rengko      81383691374 cek distributor komo    4/11/2012                   33x12.5x15  ban rosi    TELP        DKI Jakarta 
624 Joko Prayitno               4/11/2012                   175/65/14   ban rosi    EMAIL   jokfis2001@yahoo.com    DKI Jakarta 
625 diana   Jl.landas pacu timur blok D No.5kemayoran   818772885       4/11/2012   B1603BFF    Honda   2009    jazz Rs ban 185/55/R16  ban yani    YM  diana.william@ymail.com Jakarta Pusat   deal
626 Indra   Jln.Terusan I Gusti NgurahRay Pondok Kopi                                                       
    8129496491      4/11/2012   B8723KF Suzuki  2004    baleno  paket dasi  paket dasi  rosi    TELP    ind_dra@yahoo.com   Jakarta Timur   deal        
627 ari depok   2128639500  mau konfirmasi lagi     4/11/2012                   195/60/15   ban rosi    TELP        Depok
```

Let me get the details, look at the number 626.. the data is like this

```
626 Indra   Jln.Terusan I Gusti NgurahRay Pondok Kopi                                                       
    8129496491      4/11/2012   B8723KF Suzuki  2004    baleno  paket dasi  paket dasi  rosi    TELP    ind_dra@yahoo.com   Jakarta Timur   deal
```

But, it must be...

```
626 Indra   Jln.Terusan I Gusti NgurahRay Pondok Kopi  8129496491      4/11/2012   B8723KF Suzuki  2004    baleno  paket dasi  paket dasi  rosi    TELP    ind_dra@yahoo.com   Jakarta Timur   deal
```

And lot of my data become like that.. anybody have any idea about my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a rowbreak in the text in your database,
at the 2 rows like `$content .=$row[$x]."\t";`, use `str_replace()` to remove `\n`, or use php:s built in csv functions (like Phil) suggested.

If you want to build more complex xls, not just data in csv, you may want to read about the "Excel XML 2003"-files

```
$content .= str_replace("\n", " ", $row[$x]) . "\t";
```

**Update**

or just trim away all unnecessary whitespace

```
$content .= trim($row[$x]) . "\t";
```

Comment: it proberly some kind of whitespace that making the trouble, (as its not a visible part)

Comment: i using this $content .= str_replace("\r\n", "", $row[$x]) . "\t";... thank you dude

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attempting to build delimited data strings, you should use the built-in function [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

For example (abridged)

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv' );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: +1 for telling people to use the built in function rather than trying to recreate it (badly) themselves

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, it didn't help this time though :(